# What is the sequence for preprocessing text df with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, vectorization

I have a pandas data frame, containing two columns: sentences and annotations:

| Col 0 | Sentence | Annotation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [This, is, sentence] | [l1, l2, l3] |
| 2 | [This, is, sentence, too] | [l1, l2, l3, l4] |

There are several things I need to do:

- split to features and labels
- split into train-val-test data
- vectorize train data using:

  ```
    vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
       max_tokens=maxlen,
       standardize='lower',
       split='whitespace',
       ngrams=(1,3),
       output_mode='tf-idf',
       pad_to_max_tokens=True,)
  ```

I haven't worked with tensors before so I am a little confused about how to order the steps above and access the information from the tensors. Specifically, at what point do I have to split into features and labels, and how to access one or the other? Then, should I split into features and labels before splitting to train-val-test (I want to make it right and not use sklearn's train_test_split when I work with tensorflow) or it is the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your dataset before creating a model. After splitting you need to tokenize your sentences using

```
tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer((num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
```

After tokenizing you need to add padding to the sentence using

```
training_padded = pad_sequences(training_sequences, maxlen=max_length, truncating = trunc_type)
```

Then you can train your model with the data. For more details please refer to this working [code example](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/39d2579e86f3e214e73373b45687f62b). Thank You.